# How do I use firebug to debug an app that uses jQuery, when the reported error is in jquery (the data passed to jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, firebug

Often the error in the console does not include a trace or error object, but just a simple message like :

```
object is undefined
    length = object.length,
```

so I can't easily find the part of the app that is calling jquery with the faulty data.

At present I am tracking them down by entering a long trail of logs until I find the broken code. This is time consuming and is becoming more so as the app grows in complexity.  Is there an easier way?

Edit: to add screenshot

[image]

Comment: step through the code using the debugger.

Comment: Errors like this are commonly caused by plugins receiving variables in the wrong format, or missing elements on the page.

Comment: @NimChimpsky "At present I am tracking them down by entering a long trail of logs until I find the broken code."... Fine for small apps, but it becomes very cumbersome with 10's of thousands of lines of code.

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan In this case it is a $.each I can tell that from the line number in the jquery error. In this instance there are several dozen places that could be causing the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the console where you see the error:

[image]

click the circled part so that it becomes fully red:

[image]

then refresh the page. Firebug will break at the error, interrupting the execution of the script at that precise point.

[image]

You can now examine the stack trace (which includes the call stack), and use "Watch" to watch the value of variables.

Comment: Sorry, spoke to soon. This problem with this approach is that it breaks on every instance of that line of code running, not just the error. In this case dozens of times, which introduces timeout issues by the time I get to the piece of code in question. Thanks for the tip though, that will be useful in other cases.

Comment: Solved this by adding a break condition in the script window. So it only breaks when the object is undefined and not in all other instances.

Answer (score 0):

in firebug you can write `conlose.log(object name)` then open the console you will get complete object.

Comment: The problem in this case is that the object is undefined, so printing it out tells me nothing. What I need to know is where jquery was called.

Answer (score -1):

Use debugger (inside the function calls where u expect to receive values from controller)inside the script.

Comment: As I said above, that is what I do, but this is a large app. It can be doing many things simultaneously. My problem is tracking down which function is causing the problem. I need some kind of stack to track down the calling function.

Comment: @SystemicPlural Interesting to know - I've never failed to find one when I've looked. Do you happen to know in what scenarios?